# Django Rest Framework Request AssertionError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Into my app, i'm using Django + Rest Framework.
I got the following error :

.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 160, in **init**
    .format(request.**class**.**module**, request.**class**.**name**)

AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `appname.views.AppViewSet`.

## Class View

Class AppViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  . ....

## function

def list(self, request):
    pass

Django 2.1.4

Helps

Comment: You forgot to call `.as_view()` in the urls.

Comment: router = routers.DefaultRouter()

Comment: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Comment: path('', include(router.urls))